# SQL Server Cross Permutations from a single table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Quite a tricky scenario. I have a table as below. Basically I want to get all combinations of ranges from each RangeSet in SQL Server 2012.

Best I show an example of structure and desired output. The problem is the number of RangeSetID's can be dynamic and the number of RangeID's can be dynamic in each range set

```
RangeID RangeSetID
------------------
1          4
2          4
3          4
4          4
5          2
6          2
7          2
8          2
9          2
10         2
11         1
12         1
13         1
14         1
15         1
16         1
17         3
18         3
19         3
20         3
```

I need the output to recursively create the below dataset of rates:

```
1 5 11 17  (first from range4, first from range2, first from range1, first from range3)
1 5 11 18 (first from range4, first from range2, first from range1, second from range3)
1 5 11 19 (first from range4, first from range2, first from range1, third from range3)
1 5 11 20 (first from range4, first from range2, first from range1, fourth from range3)
1 5 12 17 (first from range4, first from range2, second from range1, first from range3)
1 5 12 18 (first from range4, first from range2, second from range1, second from range3)
1 5 12 19
1 5 12 20
```

And so on until I reach the last RangeID from each RangeSetID and result in

```
4 10 16 20 (last from range4, last from range2, last from range1, last from range3)
```

Which will ultimately result in the below where RateID 1 is showing the first result vertically to allow for the dynamic number of RangeSetID's

```
RateID    RangeID
------------------
  1         1
  1         5
  1         11
  1         17
  2         1
  2         5
  2         11
  2         18
```

This should result in 11,000 rows (approx). I have tried CROSS JOIN's etc but I cannot get this working at all.

Any geniuses out there please?

Thanks

Comment: Is it OK to use a user defined function?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you have four groups, then the logic would be:

```
select t1.rangeid, t2.rangeid, t3.rangeid, t4.rangeid
from t t1 cross join
     t t2 cross join
     t t3 cross join
     t t4
where t1.rangesetid = 1 and
      t2.rangesetid = 2 and
      t3.rangesetid = 3 and
      t4.rangesetid = 4;
```

If you do not know the number of values of `rangesetid`, then you will need to use dynamic SQL.  A SQL `SELECT` statement returns a fixed set of columns -- so you cannot have a variable number based on the number of values of a column.

Comment: Yes I wouldn't know how many groups I have.. This is dynamic so unfortunately I cannot do this.  What is the Dynamic SQL alternative? Please see the end result as I wouldn't need the columns but more so a RateID and the permutations underneath

Answer (score 0):

Try this dynamic SQL query.

```
 declare @i int = 1;
 declare @count int = 0;
 declare @cols varchar(max) = '';
 declare @select varchar(max) = 'select ';
 declare @join varchar(max);
 declare @where varchar(max);
 declare @query varchar(max);

 declare @range varchar(100);
 declare @prevrange varchar(100);
 declare @rangeid varchar(100);

 select @count =count(distinct RangeSetID) from [Range];

 while @count > 0
 begin

     set @range = 'Range' + cast(@i as varchar(max));
     set @rangeid = 'RangeID' + cast(@i as varchar(max));

     set @cols = @cols + @rangeid + ', ';
     set @select = @select + @range + '.RangeID as '+@rangeid + ', ';

      if @i = 1
        begin
            set @join = ' from [Range] as ' + @range;
            set @where = 'where ' + @range + '.RangeSetID <> ';
        end
      else 
        begin
            set @prevrange = 'Range' + cast((@i - 1) as varchar(max));
            set @join = @join + ' inner join [Range] as ' + @range + ' on (' + @prevrange + '.RangeID <= ' + @range + '.RangeID)';
            if(@count = 1)
                set @where = @where + @range+ '.RangeSetID';
            else 
                set @where = @where + @range+ '.RangeSetID and '+ @range+ '.RangeSetID <> ';
        end

     set @i = @i + 1;
     set @count = @count - 1;
 end 

 set @query = ' 
;WITH CTE
AS
  (
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by '+ SUBSTRING(@cols, 0, LEN(@cols)) + ') as ''RateID'', '+ SUBSTRING(@cols, 0, LEN(@cols)) +'  FROM 
  (
    ' + SUBSTRING(@select, 0, LEN(@select)) + char(13) + @join + char(13) + @where + '
  ) as A) T
  UNPIVOT ( RangeID FOR N IN ('+(SUBSTRING(@cols, 0, LEN(@cols))) +' ))P
  )
 SELECT RateID, RangeID
 FROM CTE
 ';

 exec (@query);
```

Answer (score -1):

For the sake of simplicity, RangeSetID is assumed to start from 1 and increase by 1 (no gaps between RangeSetID's).

Create a recursive function

```
create function dbo.Permutation(@n as int) returns @tbl table (RateID int,RangeID int)
as
begin
declare @Temp1 table (RateID int identity, RangeID int)
insert @Temp1 select RangeID from tbl where RangeSetID = @n
if @n = (select max(RangeSetID) from tbl)
    insert @tbl select * from @Temp1
else 
    begin
        declare @Temp2 table  (RateID int, RangeID int)
        insert @Temp2 select * from dbo.Permutation(@n+1)
        declare @count int
        select @count = count(*) from @Temp1
        insert @tbl select (a.RateID - 1) * @count + b.RateID, a.RangeID
        from @Temp2 a cross join @Temp1 b
        insert @tbl select (a.RateID - 1) * @count + b.RateID, b.RangeID
        from (select distinct RateID from @Temp2) a cross join @Temp1 b
    end
return
end
```

Then issue the following statement

```
select * from dbo.Permutation(1)
```

Comment: This doesn't output as per list but I do get the correct combinations

Comment: What do you mean 'This doesn't output as per list'?

Comment: With a table of RateID's and RangeID's

Comment: @CR41G14, Please check my updated answer. Not very satisfied about the algorithm (must be a simpler way) but I think it's acceptably fast and produces the correct permutations.